# Rsync echoes back changed file name but does not copy it

Tags: rsync

This is my first time using rsync.  I studied the command line options and chose the ones that fit my situation.

I have two servers at different IP addresses.  Here's my command string:

```
rsync -avrtu -e ssh /var/www/html root@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:/var/www/html
```

where the x's represent the remote IP address.  I tested with one file with a new timestamp (but the file size is the same as before).  Putty echoed back the file name that had changed but it did not transfer it.

Here is what Putty echoed back:

```
sending incremental file list
html/abcde.htm

sent 12,919 bytes  received 397 bytes  1,401.68 bytes/sec
total size is 8,909,156 speedup is 669.06
```

What about my command line options (avrtu) causes the file to be recognized but not copied to the other server?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks for any help.  Like I said, this is my first time with rsync.

Comment: Is the time stamp on the file being updated on the receiving end?

Comment: No - that's the problem.